# Ways to get rid of empty if-statements?

Tags: perl

To me this code is how I think of the problem I want to solve

```
if ($b eq "" && $ok) {

} elsif ($b eq "" && !$ok) {
    print "ERROR1\n";

} else {
    print "ERROR2\n";
}
```

but it is not very pretty I suppose having an empty `if`-statement.

Are there ways to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to change the logic to what you want

```
if($b eq "" && !$ok){
    print "ERROR1\n";
}elsif( !$ok || $b ne ""){
    print "ERROR2\n";
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the trick is to invert the `if`-statement and make it the `elsif`.

Answer (score 5):

Keeping the if, but checking $b

```
if ($b eq "") {
    if (!$ok) {
        print "ERROR1\n";
    }
}
else{
    print "ERROR2\n";
}
```

Comment: This is much more clear than the other answer. Two negatives joined with "or" are always less clear than nested ifs.